# Single page PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: html, header, containers, prestashop, footer

I just can't find how to make a single page in PrestaShop 1.6
I want the same header and footer but my own html between.

Has PrestaShop something like page only with offer price?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the CMS Module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/CMS+-+Managing+Static+Content) to create static content, is that what you are looking for ?